# Difference between leg-spin & flipper

Tags: cricket, terminology

What is the difference between Leg spinner's leg-spin & Flipper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leg Spin from a bowler can be varied as **Googly**, **Top Spinner**, **slider** and ***flipper***.

1. **To bowl a googly, you grip the ball the same as you would for a leg break but hold it so your palm faces away from you.** As you bowl, you bring your elbow close to your head and cock your wrist so that back of your hand faces the batsman. You spin the ball by rotating the fingers. If done properly, the ball should turn from off to leg for right handers. If the batsman comes out of his crease and misses the googly, he can be stumped.
2. **To bowl a topspinner, grip the ball as you would a leg break. Bowl it as you would a googly,** but don't cock you wrist during the action. This should impart forward spin that will cause the ball to dip later and bounce higher.
3. **To bowl a slider, grip the ball as you would a leg break,** but hold it so that your palm faces yourself. Bowl normally. This should impart backwards spin and should feel like a horribly failed leg break. If bowled properly, however, the ball will dip earlier and keep lower to the ground.
4. **To bowl a flipper, you must hold the ball as you would normally,** but you must also have your thumb on the side. Instead of rotating your fingers and wrist to give it spin, you pinch it out between your index finger, middle finger, and thumb, kind of like trying to squeeze it. The flipper will come out faster than a leg break, won't spin, and will keep close to the ground.

For more clarification click [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Bowl-the-Leg-Spinner%27s-Variations)