# What's a "slider" and an "off the seam" bowling?

Tags: cricket, spin

I've heard these terms being used during commentary, but then quite unclear of what those actually represent.

What I assumed on *slider* is that, the bowler bowls with some side-spin on top of off-spin or leg-spin. Off the seam bowling still sounds like a mystery to me.

Would be appreciated if anyone could elaborate on these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What is a Slider?*

The slider or back spinner is the reverse of the top-spinner. Instead of bouncing and kicking as the top-spinner does, the back spinner delivery will skid onto the batsman. (Sources:[1](http://www.pitchvision.com/how-to-bowl-a-slider#/), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slider_(cricket)))

This article from [cricket.com.au](http://www.cricket.com.au/video/windows-10-analyser-shane-warne-yasir-shah-secret-of-the-slider-australia-pakistan-highlights-mcg/2016-12-30) will help in understanding slider. [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MS4aOleipc)

*What is off the seam bowling?*

Seam is the raised stitching around the circumference of the ball. While [seam bowling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_bowling) is, using the seam of the ball to cause the ball to bounce in an unpredictable fashion when it hits the pitch.

*Off the seam* term is used by commentators to describe the ball that bounce unevenly or deviates from the length of the bowling (movement of the ball), after seam of the ball strikes the pitch.<sup>Need citation</sup>

Sources:[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_bowling), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_bowling), [3](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sportacademy/hi/sa/cricket/rules/the_basics/newsid_3795000/3795201.stm)

Comment: [This answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/4726/6126) is also worth reading for the difference between the various leg spin deliveries.